# javascript not showing right message at right momernt

Tags: javascript, jquery

wrote a code to handlhandle the type of messatge i should get, I am looping over the table's all trs and finding the conditions to match
Here are my conditions:
if all rows have data-mode="success" and data-pure="yes", it means the code is correct and its a success:
if any row has data-mode='success" and data-pure="no", it means, it is a warning,
if any row has data-mode="error", it means its an error and the message is danger
I have the following code but it is always returning me 1, if there is a third condition,

```
function checkTableData() {
                var allTables = $('#tableBody');
                var highestValue = -1;
                for (var i = 0; i < allTables.length; i++) {
                    var table = allTables[i];
                    var trs = $(table).find('tr');
                    for (var j = 0; j < trs.length; j++) {
                        var tr = trs[j];
                        var dataSuccess = $(tr).attr('data-mode');
                        var dataPure = $(tr).attr('data-pure');
                        console.log(highestValue);
                        if (dataSuccess === 'success' && dataPure === 'yes' && highestValue < 0) {
                            highestValue = 0;
                            console.log('0');
                        } else if (dataSuccess === 'success' && dataPure === 'no' && highestValue < 1) {
                            highestValue = 1;
                            console.log('1');
                        } else if (dataSuccess === 'error') {
                            console.log('2');
                            errorCount++;
                            if (errorCount >= 1) {
                                console.log('more than 2');
                                return 2;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return highestValue;
            }
```

i need some guidance on it, Thanks

Comment: `$("#tableBody")` will give you the one element on the page with that id. There can be only one, as id values must be unique.

Comment: yes, it  is unique for a single page

Comment: Also you can probably do all the logic with two or three jQuery calls to look for "bad" elements, instead of doing the looping explicitly.

Comment: Then you don't need the outer `for` loop.

Comment: can you guide and rewrite the code which properly please thanks

Comment: `$("#tableBody tr[data-success='error']")` will give you a list of "error" rows.

Comment: If you were to post some (simple, minimal) snippets of your HTML to demonstrate the various requirements (one snippet to demonstrate each of the messages/requirements, one for *each* requirement) it would be easier to help you. Also, what is `highestValue` doing, it's set to `-1` on each loop and then it's tested against the values of 0 and 1, and `errorCount` is incremented but never initialised.

Comment: that seems to be the problem, but can spin my head around why it is going basically i am using this function in a check to make sure what kind of class i am getting, 

https://jsfiddle.net/bu7t2k5c/, the way it is called, the editable function is called first on page and every time something changes on the page, that function is called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try `filter()` method:

```
function checkTableData() {
    let dataSuccess = $('#tableBody tr').filter((index, element)=>
        $(element).attr('data-mode') == 'error').length == 0;
    let dataPure = $('#tableBody tr').filter((index, element)=>
        $(element).attr('data-pure') == 'no').length == 0;

    if (dataSuccess && dataPure) return 'Correct'
    if (dataSuccess && !dataPure) return 'Warning'
    if (!dataSuccess) return 'Error'
}
```